# Rx java OutOfMemory

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactivex

EDITED: see this question which is more clear and precise:
[RxJava flatMap and backpressure strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322480/rxjava-flatmap-and-backpressure-strange-behavior)

I'm currently writing a data synchronization job with RxJava and I'm quite novice with reactive programming and especialy RxJava library.

My job is quite simple I have a list of element IDs, I call a webservice to get each element by ID, do some processing and do multiple call to push data to DB.

I load the data from WS with 1 io thread and push the data to DB with multiple io threads. 
However I always end-up with OutOfMemory error.
I thought first that loading the data from the WS was faster than storing them in the DBs.

But as both WS call and DB call synchronous call should they exert backpressure on each other?

Thank you for your help.

My code pretty much look like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int MAX_CONCURRENT_LOAD = 1;
    int MAX_CONCURRENT_STORE = 2;

    List<Integer> ids = IntStream.range(0, 10000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Observable.from(ids)
        .flatMap(this::produce, MAX_CONCURRENT_LOAD)
        .flatMap(this::consume, MAX_CONCURRENT_STORE)
        .toBlocking().forEach(s -> System.out.println("Value " + s));

    System.out.println("Finished");
}

private Observable<Integer> produce(final int value) {
    return Observable.<Integer>create(s -> {
        try {
            if (!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
                Thread.sleep(500); //Here I call WS to retrieve data
                s.onNext(value);
                s.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            s.onError(e);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

private Observable<Boolean> consume(Integer value) {
    return Observable.<Boolean>create(s -> {
        try {
            if (!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
                Thread.sleep(10000); //Here I call DB to store data
                s.onNext(true);
                s.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            s.onNext(false);
            s.onCompleted();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Comment: you can have a look at : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure which is what you need

Comment: I don't quite understand how this will help me. Backpressure drop will means I will lose data and I don't want to. Backpressure buffer will means I will batch data together so this might help but if I cannot send those buffer fast enough I will still have my problem and this is what I expect.

Comment: Are you getting the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread` error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your WS is poll based so if you use `fromCallable` instead of your custom Observable, you get proper backpressure:

```
return Observable.<Integer>fromCallabe(s -> {
    Thread.sleep(500); //Here I call WS to retrieve data
    return value;
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Otherwise, if you have blocking WS and blocking database, you can use them to backpressure each other:

```
ids.map(id -> db.store(ws.get(id)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.toBlocking().subscribe(...)
```

and potentially leave off subscribeOn and toBlocking as well.

Comment: Actually I don't understand why I have an OutOfMemorry issue with my code. What is actually taking more and more memory?